# List only interface names for ifaces that have 'parent: eth0' field in ifconfig output with sed and/or grep

Tags: linux, networking, sed

`ifconfig` output:

```
lo: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 33192
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
eth0: flags=8b43<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        address: 01:02:03:04:05:06
        media: Ethernet 1000baseT full-duplex
        status: active
        inet 192.168.0.10 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 192.254.255.255
        inet alias 0.0.0.0 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 255.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::0:0:0:01%eth0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
vlan01: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        vlan: 01 priority: 0 parent: eth0
        address: 01:02:03:04:05:06
        inet 192.168.0.11 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 192.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::0:0:0:02%vlan01 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6
        inet6 2a03:0:0:0::e1 prefixlen 64
```

Note, that for `vlan01` there is a record 'parent: eth0'.
What I need is to get `vlan01` for this particular output.
I have only `sed` and `grep` at my disposal.

Is it possible with `ifconfig -a | sed '...'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that with sed:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

# If it begins with anything except whitespace, trim it down to the
# bit before ":", and store that into hold space.
/^[^ ]/{
s/:.*//
h
}

# If we see "parent: eth0", then print the hold space.
/parent: eth0/{
g
p
}
```

With your input, this outputs `vlan01` (and a newline).

Answer (score 0):

Using only `grep`:

```
ifconfig | grep -B1 parent | grep -oh ^[a-z0-9]*
# -B num - Print num lines of leading context before matching lines.
# -o Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

This outputs `vlan01` for the output provided in your question. Note that my example only looks for `parent`. The pattern should be updated to reflect what you want - `parent: eth0`or other.